# Is Qt4/Qt5 QListWidget slow?

Tags: performance, qt

I'm planing on creating an application that will need to receive/show a lot of data in a QListWidget (or maybe QListView/QListModel) (I'm open to alternatives). 
The QListWidget will receive a huge number of items (+100) each second. I'll need to show all those items if/when scrollbar is used, and I'd like to achieve a non-sluggish effect.

If you have used Procmon (Windows only), that's a good example about what I'm talking about.

My question is: Can Qt handle that much data without being slow? What implementation should I take in mind?

Comment: How much is that huge number of items per second? 100? 1000? 10000? More?

Comment: Let's say 200 items per second, with a few fields (let's say 10) per row

Comment: Well, isn't it obvious that if you get 200 items per second, then this is not a UI element, at least not visual at the same time, how is a user supposed to interact with a list that gets 200 entries each second? Bad idea...

Comment: @ddriver please read my comment in Roku's answer :)

Comment: Well, this is the way every simple website functions. If you get a million results, they are not displayed at the same time in a single view. You only use the view to show a portion of the items, and give the user the ability to navigate which portion of the items is he looking at.

Comment: IIRC Qt 4.7's ListView/Widget was really laggy with many items but was improved in 4.8. I've no idea about Qt5.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating a small prototype and trying if the performance is good enough for you. I would say that QListView might be fast enough for you. Actually, when I worked with similar log views, I found the QTableView a little bit faster than the QListView.

But you should also consider whether the list view is the best possible user interface at all. When you have, lets say, 1 million items in the list (after an hour and a half), the scroll bar will be useless. You cannot use it for fine grained scrolling anymore except by clicking up/down arrows. And when you get 200 new items per second, it is not very useful to constantly draw those new lines, the user cannot read them anyway.

Comment: I won't scroll automatically, but I do want all the data to be available if users decides to scroll. About using something else, I thought about it but I haven't found any good replacement. I need the functionality of a ListView (sorting, columns), but as I said, I'm open to ideas!

Comment: Then just create a prototype using the QTableView, you will find out quite soon if it is not fast enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

### Alternative 1

For showing a log, you can also use `QTextDocument` or `QTextEdit`.  The implementation is more straight forward, and there is probably less overhead.

If you mix that in with a `QSyntaxHighlighter`, then you can have a very readable easy to use log stream.

### Alternative 2

You could also implement some sort of paging or grouping of your data, where you can jump to the beginning easily or the most recent easily.

### Alternative 3

Another idea you could look at, is that most people don't want to try to look at so much data at once.  You could aggregate the calls, and tally them up.

For example:

```
State 1 abcd
State 1 abcd
State 1 abcd
State 1 abcd
State 2 efg
```

could be represented as

```
State 1 abcd (x4)
State 2 efg (x1)
```

### Alternative 4

Or you could go with a graphical approach.  Draw the stream of data using something like `Qwt` or `QGraphicsView` in some manner that makes sense for the large quantities of data you are displaying.

### Alternative 5

And finally, another way that may prove useful is to write it to the harddrive.  Then have a button if the user wants to see the current log file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Alternative 1 isn't viable as I'm not showing a log. Each row needs to be separated as a proper row, not a line of text. Alternative 2 isn't viable either, the idea requires data to be "on a single page", read it as infinite scroll if you prefer. Alternative 3 isn't bad as idea, but the chance two rows will have same values are really small. Alternative 4 is a no-no. The kind of data I'm representing needs text, no graphs. Alternative 5: not a log file and data must be shown in real time, so saving to HDD and showing later is not functional for what I want. But thank you for the ideas!